# Custom Dialog Width and Height based on device screen size

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using dialog view as follows. If I choose the height to `1000`, it fits very well to `10` inch screen, but when I install it on `7` inch, it is quite big.

I wonder how to handle that issue?

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
   base.OnCreate(bundle);
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CustomDialogView);
   this.Window.Attributes.Height = 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the height of the device divided by the pixel density to get `dp`:

#### Example: 66% of the device's height:

```
this.Window.Attributes.Height = (int)((Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density) * 0.66);
```